# How to apply a function to every set of three in a list?

Tags: python

The list is 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 1
How would I get the output to be

2,4,5

1,2,3

3,5,1

And then be able to apply a function to each of these three lists?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Some obscure stuff follows: `a = [2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 1]; list(zip(a[::3],a[1::3],a[2::3]))`.

Comment: Try `range` with `step=3` to obtain the starting indices of sublist. Say, `range(0, len(the_list), 3)`.

Comment: Another: `list(zip(*[a[i::3] for i in range(3)]))`.

Answer (score 0):

its simple

```
mylist = [2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 1]
subset_len = 3
print([mylist[subset_len*i:subset_len*(i+1)] for i in range(len(mylist)//subset_len)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
data = [2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 1]

elements_for_list = 3

splitted_data = [data[i: i+elements_for_list] for i in range(0, len(data), elements_for_list)]

for values in splitted_data:
    # apply the sum function on each list
    print(sum(values))
```